# Missing Quote for String in Locals

Tags: vb.net, string

I read in a `Byte Array` generated from a function called from an external DLL file and then converted (encoded) it into a String.  In the Locals window (shown below), `msg` does not have a trailing double-quote.

Is this a bug, glitch, or a sign something is wrong?

**Code:**

```
    Dim msgC(32) As Byte
    Dim msg As String, length As Integer = 32

    HW(msgC, length)

    msg = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(msgC)

    Dim x As String = "hi", y As String = " ho"
    Dim z As String = x & y
```

**Locals:**

```
msg     "Hello World    String
msgC    {Length=33}     Byte()
x       "hi"            String
y       " ho"           String
z       "hi ho"         String
```

Comment: Is the Value column in the locals window so narrow that it's cutting off the closing quotation mark?  Try widening it.

Comment: Nope.  I removed other locals (Me, e, and sender) which had longer values than msg.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio?

Comment: What does msg.Trim() give you?  GetString() might be padding out the string to 32 or 33 characters.

Comment: To confirm that the end of the string really is visible in your window, check msg.Length. You may find that it is 32 characters long (with a lot of invisible characters on the end) so that ["Hello World] is only *1/3rd* of the string, not the entire string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that this would happen if the string contains embedded null (`\0`, ASCII character code 0) characters.

Comment: That was it!  I changed the DLL to also send length and used `Substring` to trim the null characters.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the overload of GetString() that has index and count paramters: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05cts4c3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx